# ButtonGroup gap isn't uniform

Tags: css

I'll have 5 buttons in a group (labled: one, two, three, four, five) in a row. Between the buttons three and four is a larger gap than between other buttons. I'm assuming it has something to do with fractional width buttons creating larger gaps. I also tried manually doing margins. Same exact issue.

Image of the issue:
[image]

Storybook mdx:

```html
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: "column"}}>
  <div style={{paddingBottom: "15px", }}>
    <Label>I'm the parent and this is the currently selected value(s) a recieved by the onChangeSelected prop: {JSON.stringify(values)}</Label>
  </div>
  <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
    <ButtonGroup onChangeSelected={(selectedValue: string[])=> handleOnSelect(selectedValue)} selectedValuesProp={passedValue} groupClass={args.groupClass} groupSize={args.groupSize} vertical={args.vertical} >
      <Button value={ "one"}>one</Button>
      <Button value={ "two"}>two</Button>
      <Button value={ "three"}>three</Button>
      <Button value={ "four"}>four</Button>
      <Button value={ "five"}>five</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  </div>
  <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "15px"}}>
    <Button onClick={()=> setPassedValue([])}>I clear the button group</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant scss:

```
.btn-group {
  @include font-defaults;
  display: inline-flex;
  // Force the buttons to adopt the overall group radius
  border-radius: $button-group-border-radius;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: $button-shadow;
  gap: 2px;
  
  >.btn {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    // Turn off the normal button radius and shadow that's now on the group
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .btn-group-selected {
    background-color: $accent-bg;
    &:hover {
      background-color: $accent-bg-hover;
    }
    &:active {
      background-color: $accent-bg-active;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I converted your code to a simple example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biberman/e3y0wm2c/)) with plain HTML and CSS and couldn't reproduce the issue. Therefor i think it's something that you didn't post, for example: `font-defaults` or the SCSS vars. For getting an answer here it would be the best to show the issue in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...